# Enable prompt for user input during Azure release pipeline

Tags: azure-devops

As a part of Azure pre-deployment condition I need to include a pause which should prompt for user input variable which can be used inside the task.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: I need to update the variable in the Azure release task dynamically during run time. For that Is there a way to implement user prompt so that the variable will be overided.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> I need to update the variable in the Azure release task dynamically during run time. For that Is there a way to implement user prompt so that the variable will be overided.

I am afraid this is impossible to update the variable in the Azure release task dynamically during run time.

First, Azure devops does not support prompt for user input.

Second, when we queue a build/release pipeline, all the related data like variables, settings are loaded into the compiler, even if we modify the variable, the modified variable will not be reloaded into the compiler. We have to restart the compiler to recompile the modified variables.

So, it is impossible to update the variable in the Azure release task dynamically **during run time**.

To resolve this issue, we have to find other workarounds to solve this issue. For example, Usig [Settable at release time](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/release/?view=azure-devops#how-do-i-specify-variables-i-want-to-edit-when-a-release-is-created):

[image]

In this case, we could update the variable when you queue the release pipeline.

Or we could use the [Logging Command](https://github.com/Microsoft/azure-pipelines-tasks/blob/master/docs/authoring/commands.md) during the release pipeline to update the variable.

If above not resolve your question, please share the reason and situation why you want to update the variable in the Azure release task dynamically during run time, we can try other solutions.

Comment: Thanks Leo for the suggestion !! Consider i have three environment Dev, Test and Prod, I would like to fetch the status of change request from Service Now , for that i have the rest api call with variable {CHG_NUMBER} , so this number has to be given by us during deployment time. Any idea would be greatful.!!

Comment: @BhuvaneshSankaran, Thanks for your reply. It seems you are using the variable `{CHG_NUMBER}` in the REST API to get the status of change request from Service Now? Am I right? If yes, the variable `{CHG_NUMBER}` is used to for what value, so that we have to pass it during the release pipeline.

Comment: Yes for the getting the state value from  serviceNow. Please find the rest api call im using it in the release pipeline task, $user = 'username'
$pass = 'password'

$pair = "$($user):$($pass)"

$encodedCreds = [System.Convert]::ToBase64String([System.Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes($pair))

$basicAuthValue = "Basic $encodedCreds"

$Headers = @{Authorization = $basicAuthValue}

Invoke-WebRequest -Uri 'https://<service-now url>/api/now/table/change_request?sysparm_fields=number%2Cstate%2Csys_id&sysparm_limit=10&number=$(change_request_number)' -Headers $Headers

Comment: @BhuvaneshSankaran, So the variable `$(change_request_number)` is what you want to pass during the release pipeline? Why not you add it when you queue the release pipeline? We could defined different variables for different environment for this variable.

Comment: Im looking for more user friendly option !! Is that the only way to pass variable when the release pipeline is queued ?

Comment: @BhuvaneshSankaran, The answer is yes.