# Azure DevOps: prompt users to enter a value for a parameter used during deployment

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline, azure-pipelines-tasks

I would like to create a Release Pipeline that, after a few tasks, stops and prompts a user to enter a value, then continues.
In the docs I found the exact [scenario](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fkUaa.png) I was looking for, see the following [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/release/approvals/?view=azure-devops)

Unfortunately, if I read the suggested links [Manual Intervention](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/release/deploy-using-approvals?view=azure-devops#configure-maninter) and [Manual Validation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/release/deploy-using-approvals?view=azure-devops#set-up-manual-validation), it is not really explained how to reproduce the scenario.

I don't even know where to start, do you have any advice?
Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: I don't believe this is possible, as discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63046506/9116267)

Comment: I read the discussion, thank you. But is really not possible? So why is explicitly written in the official documentation?
They specifically wrote: "During deployment, a team wants to prompt users to enter a value for a parameter used by the deployment tasks, or allow users to edit the release.". You can read it clicking in my 'scenario' screenshot.

Comment: I believe it's a bit misleading.  It is trying to tell you that you can add some manual intervention to tell the users to check something for manual verification, then approve the run.  In the case of the scenario, it says you could have a pause in the release to ask users to check the pipeline variables and ensure they are set before they are used.

Comment: ...But as far as stopping the release and providing some prompt to the user to enter some value(s), that is just not possible.